# Is there a name for a non-square matrix $U$ satisfying $UU^*=I$ or $U^*U=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

We know, when $U$ is a square matrix, it is called a unitary matrix. But how about the situation when $U$ is a non-square matrix? I have searched in this site, somewhere else and some books, and get very limited answers like "semi-unitary matrix" and "right inner matrix" (correspondingly "left inner matrix" for the case $U^*U=I$). It seems that these names for this kind of matrices have not obtained widespread acceptance. At the same time, their properties are seldom discussed in matrix literature.

I will appreciate it if you can give some directions about this question including some reference articles or books.

Comment: This is impossible, since the conditions say that $U$ is invertible.

Comment: Try truncated unitary matrix?

Comment: I'm using these matrices a lot and I usually refer to them as left-unitary and right-unitary. I'm not sure if these are widely accepted terms. Wikipedia mentions semi-orthogonal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix

Comment: Matrix with orthonormal rows/columns? Element of a [Stiefel manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold)? I guess these are not particularly satisfying suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes $U$ for which $U^*U=I$ are called isometric operator(s) (especially for infinite-dimensional settings), because $U$ sends the domain isometrically to the range $\|Ux-Uy\|=\|x-y\|$.  Some authors even call that isometry (i.e. drop the surjectivity constraint).

I don't think $UU^*=I$ has a standard name.